# Weird jitter of objects in Three.js using Mali GPU

Tags: three.js, webgl, mali

I have a strange problem which has been bugging me for quite a while now, the issue is best explained by a short video:

[image: Video]

As you can see the objects in the scene have a jitter when you move the camera around but also a similar thing happens every now and then when the camera is not moving. It's been driving me crazy for a while now. This video has been taken on a Tinkerboard with TinkerOS, but the same issue is also there on a Tinkerboard with FlintOS.

On a regular laptop there is no issue and everything is moving smoothly. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if it is expected behaviour seeing the differences in hardware, so I was hoping somebody could shed some light on this.

Here is a WebGL report from the Tinkerboard: 
[image]

Here a WebGL report from my laptop:
[image]

Obviously there are differences but I have no idea if any of these difference would explain this behaviour.

Can anyone clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: How big is your white plane, and what are the near and far values on your camera?

Comment: I found that when I give the white plane some z-height it does not jitter anymore. There is however still some jitter here and there. My near and far values of the camera are 200 and 4000, I already experimented with that.

Comment: Is it possible to share a reproducer? It's hard to give specific advice without knowing exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is precision; most mobile GPUs map `mediump` variables in shaders to FP16 data types, most desktop GPUs map them FP32 data types.

What are your shaders here? Try using "highp" everywhere you compute positions.

Comment: I initialized my WebGLRenderer with the option: 'precision: highp'. Are there any other places I can specify this?

Comment: Start your vertex shader with "precision highp float;", although I think your setting will do that anyway.